# Right click on textbox for filtering doesnt fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

An event which normally fires:

```
<td style="cursor: default;">
<div class="hdrcell filter">
    <input type="text" style="width:90%; font-size:8pt; font-family:Tahoma; -moz-user-select:text; ">
</div>
```

```
$('div.filter').find('input[type=text]').mousedown(function(event) {
    debugger;
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            alert('Right mouse button pressed');
            break;
    }
});
```

I have a dhtmlx grid with filters. I want to catch the event which happens on the right click on the textboxes which are for filtering results in the grid. What can be the reason?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/cut5j/  are you seeing any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('div.filter').find('input[type=text]').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    #code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The grid has context menu, but I want to disable it when a right click on the filtering textbox occurs.

Answer (score 0):

eh, read the debugger. It's trying to find the property of null. Put the whole thing in the document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.filter').find('input[type=text]').mousedown(function(event) {
    debugger;
    switch (event.which) {
      case 3:
        alert('Right mouse button pressed');
        break;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: The grid has context menu, but I want to disable it when a right click on the filtering textbox occurs.

Comment: Something else is obviously wrong, because it does indeed work with your code as is. http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/nXAAN/ Take out the debugger or make sure to continue after the debugger stops the code.